# Have a function wait until it returns 'n' number of results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to incorporate threading into my code due to the limits of my database. My problem is I have a list of dictionaries (approx ~ 850 elements) and a list of elements (same length), and I can only query 50 of them at a time. So I use a generator to split the lists into chunks of 50.

```
def list_split(ls):
    n = 50
    for i in range(0, len(ls), n):
        yield ls[i:i + n]
```

I then pass both of these lists into a function that that essentially appends them each to a new dictionary, The **value** for each dictionary will be the query which takes approximately 2 seconds per query.

```
def query(ls1, ls2):

count = 0
query_return_dict = {}

for i, j in zip(ls2, ls1):
    for key, value in zip(i, j):
        # ret = token.query(j) replace 'value' with 'ret' once ready to run
        query_return_dict[key] = value
        count += 1

print(query_return_dict)
return query_return_dict
```

I then call them:

```
ls1 = list_split(unchunked_ls1)
ls2 = list_split(unchunked_ls2)
```

Now this is where I'm not understanding 'single' threading with this code block:

```
def main():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=query, args=(ls1, ls2))
    thread.start()

    thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm learning about threading via this [site](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-make-python-wait), but I don't know if its doing what I intend to do, I'm just really hesitant to actually run this on our database for risk of backing it up by flooding it with queries.

TL;DR,

I need to make sure that `def query(ls1, ls2):` will only start to run again once 50 queries from `ls1` (which is the list of dictionaries) have been returned and appended to `query_return_dict`, then it can run then next chunk of 50, till all elements in the query list have been queried.

ALSO:

If there is a better way to do this then threading that would be awesome too!

As requested, here is what the format for the two lists would look like, keep in mind there are approximately 850 of them:

```
ls1 = ['34KWR','23SDG','903SD','256DF','41SDA','42DFS',...] <- len 850
ls2 = [{"ity": {"type": "IDE", "butes": [{"ity": {"id": "abc34"}}], "limit": 20}}, ...] <- len 850
```

Comment: Launching a single thread, and then waiting for that thread to finish, is exactly the same as not using threads at all.

Comment: @jasonharper So I wouldn't need to incorporate the last section then? The only reason my mind went to towards threading was the fact that I want to make sure that ONLY 50 queries are done at a time. If there is a more pythonic way of doing it I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Threading is for when you want to do multiple things in parallel.  It's exactly the opposite of what you want here.

Comment: If you don't want them to be processed in parallel, don't process them in parallel. Just use a regular loop.

Comment: @jasonharper. You could use threading within the chunk though.

Comment: You also realize that your first two generator functions should be one function you call twice, right? For that matter, why aren't you zipping at the generator level?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I see what you mean, fixing that, however my underlying question still applies, regardless if threading is relevant or not, the only thing I'm worried about is making sure that only 50 queries are done at a time, if that can be done without threading then thats fine but thats why I'm here lol

Comment: Just wrote you a super-detailed answer about thread pools before I realized it's totally BS. Starting over :)

Comment: It's hard to know what "The value for each dictionary will be the query" means. Where is the code which is actually performing the query? If your issue is too many queries happening at once, it will be important for us to see this code (and know some more details about what database library you're using, etc.)

Comment: @KyleWillmon sorry about that I just put some examples up, the dictionary list is tediously long but every element is in that format. As for the database info all I know is that I can only submit 50 at time and wait till all 50 queries have been returned before I can run it again.

Comment: Is the actual query going to happen outside the inner loop? The inner loop is supposed to match the 50 query results to the original keys?

Comment: @MadPhysicist @Kyle Willomon the query is a function wrapper but it returns a dictionary: `ret = token.query(j)`

Comment: Right, so shouldn't the inner loop be over `zip(i, ret)`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not implementing that until I know it only runs 50 queries at a time, but it would be `query_return_dict[key] = ret` instead of `query_return_dict[key] = value`

Comment: So all the keys would get the same value? I don't quite understand. What is the dictionary that the query returns?

Comment: The dictionary that is passed into the query is a template for the database, it returns a dictionary in a different format in return, and sadly yes I know thats extremely vague.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler if you zip first, *then* chunk. Also, let `islice` get one chunk at a time.

```
from itertools import islice


pairs = zip(unchunked_ls1, unchunked_ls2)

# Get the next 50 elements of pairs and return as a list.
# Because pairs is an iterator, not a list, the return value
# of islice changes each time you call it.
def get_query():
    return list(islice(pairs, 50))

# Repeatedly call get_query until it returns an empty list
for query in iter(get_query, []):
    # do your query
    ...
```

Comment: For `for query in iter(get_query, []):
    # do your query` after this are you just caling `def query(ls1, ls2)` im confused on the placement for the query function

Comment: `get_query` just returns the 50 key/value pairs which you'll pass to whatever actually performs the query.

Comment: `return_dict[query] = query + 1 TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list` It runs otherwise, the only problem is appending each element from the list generated by get query as a key value pair, thats the only reason I had a dictionary